# ASP.NET MVC NuGet Glimpse Remove - Glimpse References Still Listed in HTTP_COOKIE

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpcookie, glimpse

I played around with Glimpse in my ASP.NET MVC application, and have since decided to remove it for now.  I originally installed it via NuGet and used NuGet to remove it.

It appears everything is gone, except when I examine the cookie I still see:

HTTP_COOKIE glimpseState=null; glimpseOptions=null; glimpseClientName=null; ASP.NET_SessionId=....

::I pull the above from an ELEMAH dump on an error.::

Any ideas on how to remove glimpseState=null; glimpseOptions=null; glimpseClientName=null; from the cookie?  I've searched up and down my app.configs/machine.configs/iis configs but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NuGet will only remove references to Glimpse from Visual Studio, not your browser.

You have to clear you browsers cookies to remove the reference to Glimpse that you are seeing. You will have to do it in each browser that you used Glimpse in.